# Spring Date Jpa query method always returns no data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am creating a class to store values from third party service, I have created one unique key based on combination of 2 fields(and populated while creating row) so that one data gets only stored once and, this is entity class

```
@Table(name = "HQWrapper")
@Entity
public class HQWrapper {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long hQId;
     //other fields getter setter 
    @Column(unique = true,name="uniqueRef")
    private String uniqueRef;
```

I want to fetch values based on this key uniqueref, so I created one query method in repository class

```
@Repository
public interface Repository_HQ extends JpaRepository<HQWrapper, Long>{

    @Query("select h from HQWrapper h where h.uniqueRef= :uniqueRef")
    public Optional<HQWrapper> findByUniqueRef(@Param("uniqueRef") String uniqueRef);}
```

it always returns null even though exact same query works in database. I am using MYSql (I have updated names for confidentiality there are no compile time errors data gets stored correctly)

Comment: It returns `null` or `Optional.empty()`? I'm asking because method's return type is Optional

Comment: by null I am referring no data, I have updated same thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need @Query annotation:
Just declare the method like:

```
public Optional<HQWrapper> findByUniqueRef(String uniqueRef);
```

This will be enough.

While working on one project I used :

```
@Repository
public interface TagRepository extends JpaRepository<Tag,Long> {

    @Query("FROM Tag t WHERE t.name = :tagName")
    Tag findTagByName(String tagName);
}
```

Try in this format.

Comment: Hi, I tried without @Query at first then also tried native query but didn't work

Comment: While working on one project I used :
```
@Repository
public interface TagRepository extends JpaRepository<Tag,Long> {

    @Query("FROM Tag t WHERE t.name = :tagName")
    Tag findTagByName(String tagName);
}
```

Try in this format.

Comment: I added one code snippet in my answer please check it.